# Adding recorded voice recognition iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, speech-recognition, voice-recording

In my program I have some recorded voice. After that I need to recognition it, for example: I launched program, saying something, and when program received word that have been recorded it shows UIAlertView. Anybody knows any sdk or example code? Thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope the below link will helpful for you. They will also provide sample app for recognizing sounds. Download it and try it.

[Ispeech SDK](http://www.ispeech.org/)

Please note that ispeech does not perform natural voice recognition and the advertising materials are very misleading. The voice recognition piece of iSpeech requires a set vocabulary similar to the open source (and free) OpenEars SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Nuance recently updated their developer program to give mobile developers limited free access to their speech recognition servers. Look at http://dragonmobile.nuancemobiledeveloper.com/public/index.php

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use network to transfer audio, try OpenEars, the library for embedded speech recognition on IPhone

http://www.politepix.com/openears